# SC.oEmbed returns null in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

Using the [SoundCloud Javascript SDK](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/javascript-sdk), I am running the following test code:

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: MY_CLIENT_ID
});

SC.oEmbed(MY_TRACK_URL, function (results) {
    alert(results);
});
```

This returns a result object on all modern browsers, but null on Internet Explorer (7 etc.)

Is something wrong with the current Javascript SDK?

Answer (score 0):

This example works fine for me in IE 9: http://jsfiddle.net/johannes/mJGQr/

Could be an issue with the Flash fallback that is used for IE cross domain requests.
Which version of IE and Flash are you running?

Comment: I get two errors when accessing that example using IE7:`Object doesn't support this property or method` and `'length' is null or not an object`

Comment: I am using Internet Explorer 7.0.6002.18005 and Flash 11.1.102.55.